# CDP Experience / Decision Model Error: "API response must be valid JSON"

Tags: cdp, sitecore-personalize

Running into this invalid `JSON` error when I try to use my decision model to send offer data to be used in the experience. I've tested the decision model in test canvas and see that the offer is returned as an output of `decisionModelResultNodes`. I then copy this "kitchen-sink" freemarker snippet into the API tab that I found in the `CDP` tool that is recommended for capturing decision offers:

```
{
  <#if (decisionModelResults)??>
  "decisionValues": [
    <#if (decisionModelResults.decisionModelResultNodes)??>
    <#list decisionModelResults.decisionModelResultNodes as result>
    <#if (result.outputs)??>
    <#list result.outputs as output>
    <#list output as outputName, outputValue>
    <#if (!outputValue?is_hash) && outputName != "ruleId">
    {
    "decisionType": "${result.type}",
    "trackingUrl" : "${createContentTrackingURL('myContentID')}",
    "decisionName" : "${result.name}",
    "outputName" : "${outputName}",
    "outputValue" : "${outputValue}"
    }<#if output_has_next>,</#if>
    </#if>
    </#list>
    </#list>
    <#if result_has_next>
    <#if decisionModelResults.decisionModelResultNodes[result?index + 1].outputs?size != 0>,</#if>
    </#if>
    </#if>
    </#list>
    </#if>
  ],
  </#if>
  <#if (offers)??>
  "decisionOffers": ${toJSON(offers)},
  </#if>
  "guest": {}
}
```

With this, I get `API response must be valid JSON` error, but the response they show me looks like valid `JSON`, and the decision model returns an offer in the test canvas so I'm not sure what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your decision model to your Full Stack Experience? Can you see the decision model in the data selector?

Example of the data selector is shown here: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-personalize/use-dynamic-decision-model-data-in-the-api-response-for-an-interactive-experiment-718162.html